# citation numbering order issue for multiple citations

Tags: multiple-citations

I have cited a reference in the source body as reference 1, then reference 2, and reference 3 followed in order, but the issue is, after recompiling at the position of reference 1 it appeared as [2] and in Bibliography section the reference 1 goes down and stated as the Reference 2.

```
Renewable energy was shared around 11\% of total global energy 
consumption and 29\% of electrical power generation in 2020 only 
\cite{r1}. Among the sources of renewable energy wind energy is 
the most abundant worldwide and cost-effective than renewable 
sources, which is using since ancient times for milling, pumping 
and grinding grains purposes \cite{r2,r3_Yannopoulos2015}.
```

[image]

Comment: You must post an MWE (a minimal amount of code which reproduces your issue)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Assuming you employ BibTeX -- a nontrivial assumption, by the way, to create the formatted bibliographic entries and the citation call-outs, do please reveal which bibliography style and which citation management package (if any) you employ. Please also clarify that you wish the citation call-outs in the body of the document to be numbered by their first appearance in the document.